# UITableView row color changing after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
Code:
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
}
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

cell.textLabel.text = @"testing";
if(indexPath.row == 1){
    cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColorMake(kOrangeColour);
}

return cell;
```

}

I have a tableview with 14 rows in storyboard.I made change color of 2 row (i.e.1 index).When i scroll up and down the tableview for many times then i found the 14 row(i.e 13 index) color also changed.now both the row 1 and 14 are in orange color.As i coded it should change color of only one row.Why this happening?any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: UITableViewCells are reusing while scrolling.. So you need to restore original textColor of your label if a row isn't equal to 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
if(indexPath.row == 1){
    cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColorMake(kOrangeColour);
} else {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // change is here
}
```

instead of

```
if(indexPath.row == 1){
    cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColorMake(kOrangeColour);
}
```

During reusability of `UITableViewCell`, you have to declare the `if` and `else`.

Comment: One more useful information to you... you can try using a wonderful color generation class https://github.com/goppinath/GOExtendedUIColor with more than 200 X11 defined colors rather defining UIColorMake().